# Edit multiple images on a single UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

Need to select multiple images from gallery and add all images on single uiview then edit(pinch,zoom & rotate) & save each images then again edit all images on single uiview.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

For that you to create your own collection view and use [Photos.Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Photos/Reference/Photos_Framework/)

Comment: still not able to do. Can you have sample projects to edit multiple image save and edit and resave on single view?

Comment: you have to search here itself